# AWS ELB randomly returns 504 /503 response

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

We have a UI application deployed on Apache web server, within EC2 instance (t2.small). We have 2 such instances behind ELB (Classic load balacner), in 2 availability zones. From browser request is made to get javascript and css resources from server, however sometimes the network request to get these resources fails, throwing 504 timeout and sometimes 503. When we refresh the page multiple times, sometimes we get 504/503 and then on next refresh it loads fine.
I don't see any error in Apache access logs, and nothing useful in ELB logs.
Following response header is returned for 504 timeout, which I don't see for 2xx response:
"server: awselb/2.0".
I have tried keeping just one instance as well, but still this issue is reproducable.
Any debugging pointers appreciated. TIA

Comment: any update on this?